# Align individual letters below each other

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to create something like this:
[image: aligned letters]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c c }
   C&R&Y&P&T&O&G&R&A&P&H&Y \\ 
   A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I'm sure there should be an easier way to achieve this but I don't know of any. If there is any way the spacing to be minimal it would be great too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,tokcycle}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
OP Method:
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c c }
   C&R&Y&P&T&O&G&R&A&P&H&Y \\ 
   A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L \\
\end{tabular}

\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}% INTER-COLUMN GAP
\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}% BASELINESKIP FOR LONG STACKS
Stack: \tabbedCenterstack{
   C&R&Y&P&T&O&G&R&A&P&H&Y \\ 
   A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L}

Token Cycle:\\
\tokencycle{\makebox[4ex]{#1}}{}{#1}{\makebox[4ex]{#1}}
  CRYPTOGRAPHY\\
  ABCDEFGHIJKL\\
   MY TEST
\endtokencycle

ttfamily and spaceskip:\\
\ttfamily\spaceskip=2ex
  C R Y P T O G R A P H Y\\
  A B C D E F G H I J K L
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you go about creating a new command for the token cycle method?

Comment: @Rokner A direct adaptation would be `\newcommand\cry[1]{\tokencycle{\makebox[4ex]{##1}}{}{##1}{\makebox[4ex]{##1}}#1\endtokencycle}`.  However, because of how arguments are tokenized, you would need to place `%` after your \\ in the argument, or an extra space would be introduced.

Comment: @Rokner Tokcycle can check for this anomaly and correct for it, but it makes the code a bit longer: `\newif\ifignore
\tokcycleenvironment\crypto
  {\addcytoks{\makebox[4ex]{##1}}\ignorefalse}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}\tctestifx{\\##1}{\ignoretrue}{\ignoretrue}}
  {\ifignore\else\addcytoks{\makebox[4ex]{##1}}\fi\ignorefalse}
\newcommand\crypt[1]{\crypto#1\endcrypto}`.  Here, you could use either `\crypt{...}` or `\crypto...\endcrypto`.  This approach is probably safer in any event than my prior comment.

Comment: @Rokner What the extra code does is check if the token is a \\, it sets a flag to ignore an immediately following space.  Also, rather than outputting tokens directly, it gathers them in the `\cytoks` register and dumps them at the end.  This enhances capability, for example, allowing inputs like `CRY\textit{PTO}GRAPHY\\
  ABCDEFGHIJKL\\
   MY TEST`, which will honor the italic, even as it spaces things out and aligns them.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c c c c }
   C&R&Y&P&T&O&G&R&A&P&H&Y \\
   A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L
\end{tabular}

\begin{verbatim}                                                                
   CRYPTOGRAPHY                                                                 
   ABCDEFGHIJKL                                                                 
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, an implementation of Caesar's cipher so you don't even need to choose the second line. The width reserved for each character is the same as the widest one in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\caesar}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \char_generate:nn
     {
      `##1 + (#1)
      \int_compare:nT { `##1 + (#1) < `A } { +26 }
      \int_compare:nT { `##1 + (#1) > `Z } { -26 }
     }
     { 11 }
   }
  \dim_zero:N \l_tmpa_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box > \l_tmpa_dim}
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box > \l_tmpa_dim}
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}{wc{\l_tmpa_dim}}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { & } \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { & }
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\caesar{-2}{CRYPTOGRAPHY} \qquad \caesar{2}{CRYPTOGRAPHY}

\bigskip

\caesar{2}{APWNRMEPYNFW} \qquad \caesar{-2}{ETARVQITCRJA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really cool I admit it. It's a bit above my understanding but it's still cool to see what is possible in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this alignment without tabular etc. macros, use only TeX primitives:

```
\def\cryp #1{\hbox\bgroup \crypA#1\end}
\def\crypA #1{\ifx\end#1\egroup\else \hbox to1em{\hss#1\hss}\expandafter\crypA\fi}

\cryp{CRYPTOGRAPHY}
\cryp{ABCDEFGHIJKL}
```

You can change `\hbox to1em` to `\hbox to<another value>` as you wish.